# Repeat function every id named "" with jquery

Tags: jquery, sql, html

Ok i have this function what it does is takes the value of id time, user, title, and bodytext.

Function to insert into sql.

```
function getblogpost() {

    var date = $('#time').text();
    var user = $('#user').text();
    var title = $('#title').text();
    var textbody = $('#bodytext').text();
    var postid = $('#pid').text();
    dbsql.transaction(
        function(transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql(
                'INSERT INTO blogpost (postid, date, user, title, textbody) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);', 
                [postid, date, user, title, textbody], 
                function(){

                }, 
                errorHandler
            );
        }
    );

    return false;

}
```

And this would be the html that the above function works with.

```
<div id="main">
<div id="time">some text..</div>
<div id="user">some text..</div>
<div id="title">some text..</div>
<div id="bodytext">some text..</div>
<div id="pid">some text..</div>
</div>

<div id="main">
<div id="time">some text..</div>
<div id="user">some text..</div>
<div id="title">some text..</div>
<div id="bodytext">some text..</div>
<div id="pid">some text..</div>
</div>

<div id="main">
<div id="time">some text..</div>
<div id="user">some text..</div>
<div id="title">some text..</div>
<div id="bodytext">some text..</div>
<div id="pid">some text..</div>
</div>
```

The problem im having is that i dont know how to repeat one function for every div named main. Right now it only does it for the first main div but does now move onto the next main  div.

What could be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

First off you can't have more than 1 element with a single id. You need to uses classes.

the html can look like this:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="time">some text..</div>
  <div class="user">some text..</div>
  <div class="title">some text..</div>
  <div class="bodytext">some text..</div>
  <div class="pid">some text..</div>
</div>
```

and the code like this:

```
 function getblogpost(div) {

    var date = $(div).find('.time').text();
    var user = $(div).find('.user').text();
    var title = $(div).find('.title').text();
    var textbody = $(div).find('.bodytext').text();
    var postid = $(div).find('.pid').text();
    dbsql.transaction(
        function(transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql(
                'INSERT INTO blogpost (postid, date, user, title, textbody) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);', 
                [postid, date, user, title, textbody], 
                function(){

                }, 
                errorHandler
            );
        }
    );

    return false;

}
```

then call it like this:

```
$('.main').each(function(){ 
  getblogpost(this);
});
```

Comment: I dont know why but every time i try this
$('.main').each(function({ 
  getblogpost(this);
}));
it stops the sql from starting.

Comment: never mind fixed it by using $('.main').each(function(){getblogpost(this);});

Comment: sure enough! Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ids, use classes.

```
$('.main').each(function(){ 
   //do something with $(this)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't duplicate id's like that:  it makes your HTML document invalid and will cause you nothing but problems.

You'll need to use iteration.  Name each div id `main1`, `main2`, etc...  Then you can collect all of the data you need.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like this but then i would have to have made some sort of increment system to go with it. but i do like this idea as now you can find specific id's among a lot. Thanks for the help!